# Check with jQuery value of checkbox from custom admin panel

Tags: jquery, admin-menu

i am trying to create my first admin panel for my theme.
I have a simple checkbox which i think is working.

Where is this information stored?
Is this information stored in the database? How can i then check it's value? 
I would like to read this value with jQuery. Is it possible?

This is my array for the checkbox:

```
array( "name" => "Followers Count: ",
"desc" => "Select if you want to display the number of followers of your blog (at the bottom of your widget bar)",
"id" => $shortname."_followers",
"type" => "checkbox",
"std" => ""),
```

Please let me know any other information you may need.

Thank you for your help!  =)

Comment: reading a checkbox's value with jQuery isn't really a WordPress specific thing. Although, what you might want to do after you learn the status probably is. Still, that question has been asked before at stackoverflow, no doubt. `.is(':checked')`

Comment: but with "is.(':checked')" i would check if it is checked on one specific page, right?
But i want to know the value from that checkbox (the value of that parameter in the settings) when i am on a different page.

Comment: So you need to save this somewhere. http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API